# how to deploy FreeSWITCH for an existed Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, sip, voip, freeswitch

I plan to balance the REGISTER and INVITE tasks' load of FreeSWITCH  with the help of Hadoop cluster, so my questions below,

1. i wanna know whether i can deploy FreeSWITCH for an existed Hadoop
   cluster. if not, jump to third question please.
2. how shuld i configure and deploy the FreeSWITCH.
3. is there any other solution for FreeSWITCH's load-balance.

PS: my Hadoop cluster is builed on virtual mathine by vmware, and OS is Ubuntu 14.04, Hadoop-2.6, HBase-0.98, ZooKeeper-3.6, FreeSWITCH-1.4.14.

Answer (score 0):

FreeSWITCH cluster can be built on top of an RDBMS: FreeSWITCH is using ODBC to access the database and to store the call and registration status in it. Mysql and Postgres are well-tested backends for this, and I'm not sure anyone has done it with Hadoop.